# Docker-compose + Heroku + Django + Gunicorn H14 error

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, debian, docker-compose

I am getting an H14 Heroku error when trying to deploy my built docker image to heroku.

Since the Heroku documentation says a CMD command is required and it appears that the commands in the Procfile are not actually run I am at a bit of a loss as to what to do.

**My heroku error log :** `

```
2017-11-01T11:19:47.714787+00:00 app[globus.1]: Post-processed 'admin/css/forms.css' as 'admin/css/forms.2003a066ae02.css'
2017-11-01T11:19:47.715387+00:00 app[globus.1]: 
2017-11-01T11:19:47.715389+00:00 app[globus.1]: 0 static files copied to '/globus/staticfiles', 62 unmodified, 24 post-processed.
2017-11-01T11:20:48.337975+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=kolland-globus-1.herokuapp.com request_id=e2a6eda9-e2bf-477b-9987-b5995d110b0e fwd="2.87.181.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-01T11:20:48.683132+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kolland-globus-1.herokuapp.com request_id=eb2e00ee-826a-4ddd-aa22-78e242612e8f fwd="2.87.181.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-01T11:20:48.766644+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kolland-globus-1.herokuapp.com request_id=60d645a6-8657-4236-80d9-7a8f8e880640 fwd="2.87.181.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Output of heroku ps:**

```
=== globus (Free): /start.sh (1)
globus.1: up 2017/11/01 13:19:44 +0200 (~ 17m ago)
```

**Heroku Control Panel for the app says:**

```
globus /start.sh
```

---

**My code is as follows:**

1) The start.sh script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
python manage.py migrate        # Apply database migrations
python manage.py collectstatic --clear --noinput # clearstatic files
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput  # collect static files

# Prepare log files and start outputting logs to stdout
exec gunicorn globus.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT --workers 3
#python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT  --settings=globus.settings.production
```

2) The docker-compose file :

```
version: '2'

services:
  globus:
    build: .
    image: globus:latest
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./globus:/opt/globus
```

3) Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7.14

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ADD ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
ADD ./start.sh /start.sh
ADD . /globus

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN groupadd -r django && useradd -r -g django django

RUN chown -R django /globus && chmod +x start.sh && chown django start.sh

WORKDIR /globus

CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

---

What I've tried ::

```
CMD [ "python", "./manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:$PORT", "--settings=globus.settings.production" ]
CMD ["exec", "gunicorn", "globus.wsgi", "-b", "0.0.0.0:$PORT", "--log-file", "-"]
CMD exec gunicorn globus.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT --log-file -
CMD ["/start.sh"]

&& ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"](without exec gunicorn cmd) + CMD exec gunicorn globus.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

---

Additionally I've run in the docker-compose file:

```
command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --settings=globus.settings.production
command: python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --settings=globus.settings.production
```

---

**Notes**:

**
Running docker-compose build + up locally works for **all** aforementioned aproaches provided I change $PORT to 5000.
**

I have a feeling it might have something to do with permissions because I am running docker-compose build + up as root user although am not sure how to change the Dockerfile to avoid that beyond the two lines I have added.

**dyno= connect= service=** in the error logs I believe means that the app is somehow either crashing or not exposed to the heroku router.

The databse is the Heroku Postgresql Addon and the credentials are stored in an env file. The addon works even if I run docker-compose up on my local machine.

I have a working heroku app that was deployed via git. 
When I did an:

```
heroku run bash
> ls
```

I could see the file structure
When I do the same on for this app I get nothing

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

---

**Result of the Netstat command:**

```
2017-11-01T20:50:11.186705+00:00 app[globus.1]: [2017-11-01 20:50:11 +0000] [6] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2017-11-01T20:50:11.187111+00:00 app[globus.1]: [2017-11-01 20:50:11 +0000] [6] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:18815 (6)
2017-11-01T20:50:11.202914+00:00 app[globus.1]: [2017-11-01 20:50:11 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
2017-11-01T20:50:11.187194+00:00 app[globus.1]: [2017-11-01 20:50:11 +0000] [6] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2017-11-01T20:50:11.192252+00:00 app[globus.1]: [2017-11-01 20:50:11 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2017-11-01T20:50:11.247884+00:00 app[globus.1]: [2017-11-01 20:50:11 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
2017-11-01T20:50:16.019831+00:00 heroku[globus.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-11-01T20:50:15.952136+00:00 app[globus.1]: (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
2017-11-01T20:50:15.957398+00:00 app[globus.1]: Active Internet connections (servers and established)
2017-11-01T20:50:15.957400+00:00 app[globus.1]: Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
2017-11-01T20:50:15.952156+00:00 app[globus.1]:  will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
2017-11-01T20:50:15.957400+00:00 app[globus.1]: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18815           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6/python        
2017-11-01T20:50:16.031459+00:00 heroku[globus.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2017-11-01T20:51:19.828010+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kolland-globus-1.herokuapp.com request_id=59003956-da54-4a6f-921f-70ed4930fc3e fwd="2.87.181.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-01T20:51:19.652507+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=kolland-globus-1.herokuapp.com request_id=6a090f48-214f-457b-9471-09e2995817fe fwd="2.87.181.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: First of all don't use a `ENTRYPOINT`, heroku has a open bug that i recently logged with them. So whatever you try, put all commands in series in a bash script and then try. And the last command in your script should be `exec gunicorn globus.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT`

Comment: Hiya thanks for that. I have tried that approach with `CMD ["/start.sh"]` and with  `exec gunicorn globus.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT` as the last command. No luck sadly. Works locally but not on Heroku, still an H14 err is thrown.

Comment: Do one thing, don't use exec. Launch the process in background and put a `netstat -plant` command at the end of bash script. Also add a sleep before that. See if you find things in log?

Comment: I removed exec and ran the netstat command and updated the question with the log. I'm not sure how it should normally look.